# Why are the pins of a ZIF socket usually wider than a normal socket?

Tags: pins, socket, zif

The pins of Zero Insertion Force sockets are usually wider than those of normal sockets.  This makes it difficult to piggy-back ZIF sockets on other sockets or headers.  Why are ZIF pins so wide?

Comment: Because they are folded sheet metal. The pin end has already been thinned far below the socket end; any thinner and it would break.

Comment: ZIF sockets frequently are designed to accept multiple packages, which may include both narrow and wide DIP variants, so they use broad holes to accept multiple possible chip widths. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @Hearth: I'm asking about their own pins underneath, not the slots on the top which accept the other device's pins.